# In Typescript, how to declare dispatch generic type rightly with then promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making LoginPage on boilerPlate using typescript but typeError occurred in dispatch

dispatch is no problem but i think  is not best type

so,
is anything type instead of "any"??

---

```js
const onSubmit = (e:FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch<>(loginUser(inputs))
        .then((response: { payload: { loginSuccess: boolean; }; }) => {
            if(response.payload.loginSuccess){
                props.history.push('/')
            } else {
                alert('Routing Error')
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: In both cases the Promise doesn’t return a value so what you have here is Promise<void>

Comment: Promise<void> is samething with dispatch< > ??